# How to make multiply request with rxJava

Tags: java, android, rx-java

How to make 10 parallel request with retrofit. Please help me solve this issue. I try to use zip operator, but so I can use in Java only Function9.

```
public Single<List<Response<MyResponse>>> getRequest(...) {

        return Single.zip(getNyRequest(sessionId, RequestParams.getParams( "")),
                getNyRequest(sessionId, RequestParams.getParams( "")),
                getNyRequest(sessionId, RequestParams.getParams("")),
                getNyRequest(sessionId, RequestParams.getParams("")),
                getNyRequest(sessionId, RequestParams.getParams("")),
                getNyRequest(sessionId, RequestParams.getParams("")),
                getNyRequest(sessionId, RequestParams.getParams("")),
                getNyRequest(sessionId, RequestParams.getParams("")),
                getNyRequest(sessionId, RequestParams.getParams("")),
                getNyRequest(sessionId, RequestParams.getParams("")),
                (result1, result2, result3, result4, result5, result6, result7, result8, result9, result10) -> {

                });
}
```

Comment: Please post your current code and what does not work.

Comment: It is easier to make parallel requests using coroutines if you feel easier to code in kotlin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use iterable:

```
  List<Single<String>> singles = Arrays.asList(Single.just("1"), Single.just("2"), Single.just("3"));
  Single<List<String>> zip = Single.zip(singles, objects -> Stream.of(objects).map(o -> (String) o).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

in your case:

```
 List<Single<Response<MyResponse>>> singles = Arrays.asList(getNyRequest(sessionId, RequestParams
        .getParams("")), getNyRequest(sessionId, RequestParams.getParams("")), ....);
 Single<List<Response<MyResponse>>> zip = Single.zip(singles,
        objects -> Stream.of(objects).map(o -> (Response<MyResponse>) o).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

**EDITED:** 
For repeating every 10 minutes:

```
getRequest(...).repeatWhen(c -> c.delay(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES))
.subscribe();
```

Comment: thank you for answer. And now how Can I repeat calling of this request every ten minute?

Comment: I updated the answer, if you find it usefull please accept it by clicking on  ✓, for any other questions I'd suggest to create a new question.